# How to obtain and print the data that is present in classical register after measuring the data of quantum circuit

Tags: measurement

Title: Circuit Diagram for Measurement
Give a quantum circuit diagram illustrating a basic measurement setup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.